# Max of a Tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

```
data Tree a = Null | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
     deriving (Read,Show)
```

Having a problem here, how would I find the maximum value of a binary tree?

Comment: What did you post all that code for?

Comment: If you manage to sort a tree, I don't see how it can be hard to find the maximum.

Comment: What did you try? This looks more as a problem dump than a question. Also, most of your code is irrelevant to the task: I guess you did not write it, but you merely copy & pasted from somewhere else. You should show your attempt, and describe your issues. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: i reduced the size of the code

Comment: Now the question has no (longer an) attempt of the OP side.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have suggested, you can just sort the the tree, and take the maximum. You can use your earlier `inOrder` and `makeTree` functions to create a tree sort function:

```
treeSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
treeSort xs = inOrder (makeTree xs)
```

Which gives a list of your tree items in sorted order, then just take the [`maximum`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=maximum) of this:

```
maxTree :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
maxTree xs = maximum (treeSort xs)
```

Which has this behaviour:

```
Prelude> let sortedTree = treeSort [4,3,2,1,5,6,8,7,9]
Prelude> sortedTree
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Prelude> maxTree sortedTree
9
```